# Representing XML in CSV: advice for dealing with child tags

Tags: xml, csv, data-structures

I'm building a data visualisation and I want to use CSV as my base data format for lightness and ease of use. My source data is in heavy XML, so I'm converting it to CSV, using Python and lxml.

My question is this. When I have multiple child tags within the XML, like the `<City>` tags in the following:

```
<Country>
   <Name>France</Name>
   <Cities>
   <City><Name>Paris</Name></City>
   <City><Name>Lyon</Name></City>
   </Cities>
</Country>
<Country>
   <Name>Germany</Name>
   <Cities>
   <City><Name>Berlin</Name></City>
   <City><Name>Munich</Name></City>
   <City><Name>Aachen</Name></City>
   </Cities>
</Country>
```

How should I represent them in my CSV file? I can think of two options. The first is to add a column for each city, up to CityN:

```
 Country,City1,City2,City3
 France,Paris,Lyon,,
 Germany,Berlin,Munich,Aachen
```

The second is to use an array for all the cities:

```
 Country,Cities
 France,[Paris,Lyon]
 Germany,[Berlin,Munich,Aachen]
```

It may be that the best format just depends on how I want to query the data, but I thought I would check here to see if there was a well-established or better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are going to use CSV, the array version is superior preserves the field-based structure of the document.  Without the array nomenclature, the comma is overloaded as both a field separator and as a value within field separator with no way to determine which is in play except by counting fields from the left side of the record.

The non-array version also limits your data to one nested collection per record type.  This is not an issue in the current example, but could be for another record type within your application.  Using a (single) standard approach improves clarity and maintainability.

Comment: Thanks, that was my thought too. I then have to deserialise the string into an array on the client side, but that's OK given the other advantages, I think.